# Android dynamic theming

Tags: android, api, kotlin, android-layout, theming

I want to ask if it is possible to change the system font size out of an App.
So the idea is to create an App to change some system parameters, but I don't know if I can use RRO's or the Dynamic Theme function from Android 12 or another alternative.

I read that:

> "The “Styles” option for customizing system icons, icon outlines, and
> fonts will be removed with Android 12" / © NextPit."
> https//new.in-24.com/News/111901.html

I know I can change the font size in the settings but I want to do it out of an App and maybe also change the icon size and more later.

Does anyone have a good idea of how to start or an example?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To make any system changes, you need the user to navigate to Settings App. an OTT app cannot do system level changes.
Other Possibility is, root your device and make your app as an system app.

Comment: thank you worked with root and custom rom

Comment: @RafaelJan good to hear that. Can you accept this answer please.